# What is the starting address of the location counter in a linker script?

Tags: syntax, linker, sections, linker-scripts

I downloaded the following linker script:

```
SECTIONS
 {
     /* Special section for exceptions stack.*/
     .mstack (NOLOAD) :
     {
         . = ALIGN(8);
         __main_stack_base__ = .;
         . += __main_stack_size__;
         . = ALIGN(8);
         __main_stack_end__ = .;
     } > MAIN_STACK_RAM
 }
```

I have two questions.

1. What is the default address of the location counter if this is the first `SECTIONS` command in the linker file?
2. If the default address is `0x0`, then what is the first line in the .mstack section `. = ALIGN(8);` really accomplishing? If the location counter address starts at `0x0`, then wouldn't the location counter still be `0x0` after this line  or would it be `0x8`?

Comment: It is very likely that this linker script is included inside another linker script which defines the starting VMA.

Answer (score 0):

1. The default address is where the MAIN_STACK_RAM is assigned. It should be defined in the start of the linker script.
2. The line `.=ALIGN(8)` will pad your address until it will be divisible by 8. So if the default address is `0x0`, or any other address that divides by 8, it will remain the same address.